# How to add a logo in easyadmin?

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I only managed to change the name, but I can not find on any forum the way to add with this name, a logo. Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

```
easy_admin:
    site_name: 'My admin'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/basic-configuration.html#changing-the-name-of-the-backend) you can define an image as the site name like this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
easy_admin:
    site_name: '<img src="http://symfony.com/logos/symfony_white_01.png" />'
```

You will have a logo instead of a text.